# WebApi controller not found in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, routes

I'm writing a asp.net web service which contains a web controller.
today I add a new webapi controller to my project, when I send a request to oldest controller everything is ok and I get correct response. but when I send a request to new one, my browser(MS Edge) returns this error:

> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
>   requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). (XHR): POST -
>   http://localhost:3982/api/ViewTemplates

It returns error while both of controllers are in a same namespace and place together in a folder.

I try defining my new request path

> http://localhost:3982/api/ViewTemplates

manually in WebApiConfig.cs but it doesn't work so I change this class to it's default configuration.

can you help me?

thanks

Comment: Please add more information such as how routing is defined? Maybe snippets of the code around the old and the new controller methods.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Delete bin directory, clean solution and rebuild.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I see what is wrong.my data from client side is different than definition in server side so server can't match anything.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). (XHR): POST - http://localhost:3982/api/ViewTemplates

This Error means the url you are requesting on this link  http://localhost:3982/api/ViewTemplates not exists. Check folder path or project path directory.

Second thing is most of filenames in asp project has .aspx at the end like this http://localhost:3982/api/ViewTemplates.aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer, I see what is wrong.my data from client side is different than definition in server side so server can't match anything.